# Sort dictionary and create a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to sort dictionary by values and return a string.

```
d = {'K': 1000, 'M': 1200, 'R': 600, 'T': 400}
s = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
```

And I get:

```
['M', 'K', 'R', 'T']
```

How to return keys with values in this form?

```
 1. M: 1200
 2. K: 1000
 3. R: 600
 4. T: 400
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to carry the values with the keys. In that case, sort according to the values, simply:

```
d = {'K': 1000, 'M': 1200, 'R': 600, 'T': 400}
s = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x : x[1], reverse=True)

print(s)
```

result:

```
[('M', 1200), ('K', 1000), ('R', 600), ('T', 400)]
```

and for display, use `enumerate` starting at `1` on the sorted items, which unpacks in `i,(k,v)` (`i` is the index, `k` and `v` are the key/values of the dict)

```
for i,(k,v) in enumerate(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x : x[1], reverse=True),1):
    print("{}. {}: {}".format(i,k,v))
```

prints:

```
1. M: 1200
2. K: 1000
3. R: 600
4. T: 400
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following

```
#1 - Sort your keys first

In [54]: d_sorted = sorted(d,key=d.get,reverse=True)

#2 - Once done, use enumerate and use the value in your sorted list to get the 
#value of your dictionary

In [55]: for i,r in enumerate(d_sorted):
    print(str(i+1)+'.',r+':',d[r])

#results
1. M: 1200
2. K: 1000
3. R: 600
4. T: 400
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
d = {'K': 1000, 'M': 1200, 'R': 600, 'T': 400}
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=True)):
   print("{}. {}: {}".format(i+1, a, b))
```

Output:

```
1. M: 1200
2. K: 1000
3. R: 600
4. T: 400
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop through the sorted values of s (either with a for loop or a comprehension as below) and use them to access the values of the dict.

```
[print(i + ": " + str(d[i])) for i in s]
```

OUTPUT:

```
M: 1200
K: 1000
R: 600
T: 400
```